# Long form of $('selector')?

Tags: jquery

Our application uses some jquery selectors to select some elements in the HTML DOM.
The `$('blabla')` syntax is quite convenient, but we also need to call the same thing but by passing a specific dom, so we're looking at the long for form of it, the form that allows us to select the document.

What is the long form of `$('selector')`?

Comment: Is this? `$(document).find("blabla");`?

Comment: You mean match 'blabla' beneath a specific tag? You can use `$('.foo').find('blabla')` or `$('blabla', $('.foo'))` - is that what you mean?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux What do you mean by "long form"?

Comment: No, for the full document, not a sub element.

Comment: @rup: `$('.foo blabla')` is much more readable!

Comment: @RobW Well, technically $() does'nt take a document variable, because the document is global. Is there a way to pass it as an argument?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux [`$(document).find('selector')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) / Shorthand: [`$('selector', document)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context)

Comment: @RobW $(document).find('selector')  seems to be what I'm looking for then.

Comment: @ThiefMaster True. I meant that as an example selector but in practice I was expecting him to use a variable that contains a selector for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but to put the `document` into a jQuery object use:

```
$(document);
```

If this is not what you want, please edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: Well, I guess that's what Iam looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a context to the `jQuery()` function, which will limit the scope in which it searches for elements that match the selector. Take a look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the selector to a certain element/document, by passing it as a second argument to jQuery: `$('selector', someDocumentOrElement)`